# How can I convince my boss that ANSI C is inadequate for our new project?

Tags: c#, c, programming-languages

A few months ago, we started developing an app to control an in-house developed test equipment and record a set of measurements. It should have a simple UI, and would likely require threads due to the continuous recording that must take place. This application will be used for a few years, and shall be maintained by a number of computer science students during this period.

Our boss graduated some 30 years ago (not to be taken as an offense; I have more than half that time on my back too) and has mandated that we develop this application in ANSI C. The rationale is that he is the only one that will be around the entire time, and therefore he must be able to understand what we are doing. He also ruled that we should use no abstract data types; he even gave us a list with the name of the global variables (sigh) he wants us to use.

I actually tried that approach for a while, but it was really slowing me down to make sure that all pointer operations were safe and all strings had the correct size. Additionally, the number of lines of code that actually related to the problem in hand was a only small fraction of our code base. After a few days, I scrapped the entire thing and started anew using C#. Our boss has already seen the program running and he likes the way it works, but he doesn't know that it's written in another language.

Next week the two of us will meet to go over the source code, so that he "will know how to maintain it". I am sort of scared, and I would like to hear from you guys what arguments I could use to support my decision.

Comment: Consider asking this question on [the Programmers Stack Exchange site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Just tell him the C# version was a prototype because you could get it up and running very quickly to prove the concept. Then tell him the ANSI C version is still under development but taking a long time. If it is going to take too long he might be happy to scrap it.

Comment: Your question is mis-titled; you should have asked this question *before* directly contravening your boss's orders. :) Realistically, your question is "how can I convince my boss that the quality and speed with which I wrote the program outweighs the (slight) maintainability hassle that now exists?" You should probably focus on the quality of the program and the speed with which you wrote it :)

Comment: Does he even enforce no C99 stuff? such as declaration of local variable on function top.

Comment: Instead of simply "closing as not constructive", it would be nice if people explained their reasons for doing so. I carefully read the FAQ before posting. This is a "practical, answerable problem" that is "unique to the programming profession".

Comment: Thank you In Silico, I'll do just that. I can't vote your comment up though.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly it could blow up in your face, but if your boss isn't a complete twit he will see how much more productive you've been and be able to move forward.  C# does use a different paradigm from ANSI C, with the OOP and all, but the syntax is similar enough he should be able to figure it out.  If not leave lots of good comments in the code, and maybe be nice enough to produce some actual technical documentation he can read through.

Comment: Instead of comments in code, better to have work items so you can annotate code files and see much more information. More ALM...